# Convert one JSON structure to another using Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

Input JSON:

```
{
    "name" : "objname",
    "abc" : 1,
    "def" : 2
}
```

Desired output JSON:

```
{
    "objname" :
    {
        "abc" : 1,
        "def" : 2 
    }
}
```

I tried as shown below, but I feel it's not the correct way.

```
// This is the class object
public class Obj
{
    public string Name { get;set;}
    public string abc { get; set; }
    public string def { get; set; }
}         

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Obj>(json);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(" { ");
sb.AppendLine(obj.Name);
sb.AppendLine(" :  {");
sb.AppendLine(GetMemberName(() => obj.abc) + ":" + obj.abc + ",");
sb.AppendLine(GetMemberName(() => obj.def) + ":" + obj.abc);
sb.AppendLine(" :  }");
```

Comment: input is invalid json and so is the output

Comment: 1) Your desired output `"objname" : { "abc" : 1, "def" : 2 }` isn't even JSON, it's missing the outer `{` and `}`.  2) What have you tried so far?

Comment: Look at the homepage for this package. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json. You will see a Serialize and DeserializeObject. That's what you need. And please try before asking here.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey  input isn't, output is

Comment: input missing a comma, so JSON.NET won't parse it. JSON must start with { or [, so it will not generate that output.

Comment: then the answer is "yes"

Comment: sorry, syntax in question was incorrect. yeah, i do have tried to get solution, but failed. so tried asking here quickly. now i do have edited, it would be grateful, if i get any solution. thanks in advance.

Comment: So please show what you have tried, and what happened.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey: No, JSON doesn't have to start with `{` or `[`. It's perfectly valid to have a JSON document which is *just* a string, null token or number for example. But yes, for an object, you do need the braces.

Comment: Thanks, @JonSkeet. You are correct, since 2014 those are allowed. I'm just used to maintaining backward compatibility.

Comment: @JonSkeet :  I know its poor code, but this is what i tried.    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Obj>(input);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(" { ");
            sb.AppendLine(obj.Name);
            sb.AppendLine(" :  {");
            sb.AppendLine(GetMemberName(() =>obj.abc)+":" + obj.abc+ ",");
            sb.AppendLine(GetMemberName(() => obj.def) + ":" + obj.abc);
            sb.AppendLine(" :  }");

Comment: Please include that *in the question*, along with what `Obj` looks like, and details of what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is deserializing. You can just go to a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

Then, to get it back, you probably need to use a dictionary as well. You cannot use a predefined (even compiler generated) class, since you don't know the property name.

```
String name = (string)dict["name"];
// remove name from dictionary
dict.Remove(name);
var output = 
   new Dictionary<string,object>() {{name, dict}};
```

Then, save it back out:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output);
```

Comment: That will **not** produce the requested output => [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vlCaqA)

Comment: You will have to deserialize to a `Dictionary<string,object>` instead => [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ml1FRX)

Comment: yep, typo. fixing

Comment: yeah, saw your fiddle. I was intended as a guide, not ready to go

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Thanks a lot. Its working. I was not knowing how to leverage dictionary.